# Facegrids at ticks

Tags: graphics3d

I want to plot a 3D graphic and I want facegrids at the ticks that I specify. I've tried several solutions but I cannot get this working. The result with the code provided below is that it does its job except in the x-axis where it only draws a facegrid at the middle coordinate (and not in all ticks). Any advice is most welcome.

Here is my code:

```
Plot3D[exp[R, bn, 50], {R, 2, 100}, {bn, 1, 5},
       AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005],
       Ticks -> {{2, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
                 {0.5, 1.0,1.5, 2.0, 2.5}}, 
       Boxed -> False,
       Mesh -> {{0, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100}, 
                {1,1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5}}, 
       PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
       FaceGrids -> All,
       AxesLabel -> {"X","Y","Z"}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8115848

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be found on the 'More Information' section of the [FaceGrid doc page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FaceGrids.html#10002948) though it may not be very easy to grasp. Here's an example:

```
Plot3D[Sin[R bn/10], {R, 2, 100}, {bn, 1, 5}, 
 AxesStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
 Ticks -> {{2, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5}},
 Boxed -> False, 
 Mesh -> {{0, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100}, 
          {1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5}}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 FaceGrids -> 
   {{{0, -1, 0}, {{2, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100}, {0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5}}}, 
    {{1,  0, 0}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5}}}, 
    {{0, 0,  1}, {{2, 10, 20, 30, 50, 100}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}}
   }
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Basically what `Facegrid` specifies here is which faces to draw and what lines to draw
in each face. For each face, we need one list. An identification of the grid we are talking about is the first element of each face grid specification. This specification can be thought of the unit vector pointing straight to the grid you want to indicate, so {1,0,0} would be the $+x$ face grid, and {0,-1,0} would be the $-y$ grid.  The next element of the grid specification list is a specification of the grid lines, a list with tick values for each of the remaining coordinates. So, if the $+x$ grid is being specified this list contains a specification for the $y$ and $z$ ticks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was about to hit my head into the wall! :)