# Increase number of lines shown by FaceGrids

Tags: graphics3d

From the documentation, you can create face grids in a graphic with:

```
Graphics3D[Cylinder[], Axes -> True, FaceGrids -> All]
```

[image]

But it says nothing about increasing the number of lines in the grid. As you see, there is a line every $0.5$. What if I need a line every $.1$ or anything else? How do you change this?

Comment: possible duplicates: [Facegrids at ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3685/9490), [Understanding FaceGrids](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111197/9490)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't use the `Automatic`, `None` or `All` methods, then you must specify all the gridlines yourself.

The Details section of the [`FaceGrids`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FaceGrids.html) documentation page says how to do this. You specify the face grids as `{{face1,{xgrid1,ygrid1}},…}`.  Here face_i is `{1,0,0}`, `{-1,0,0}`, `{0,1,0}` etc, and the xgrid_i are a list of numbers specifying where to put the lines.

```
fineGrid = Range[-1, 1, 0.1];
faces = Flatten[Permutations /@ {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -1}}, 1];

faceGrids = {#, {fineGrid, fineGrid}} & /@ faces;

Graphics3D[Cylinder[], Axes -> True, FaceGrids -> faceGrids]
```

[image]